# Default video player not automatically expanded since last update?

Tags: video

Lately I've noticed that the default video player on Android is not automatically expanding to the full size of the screen, instead it is playing videos at the original resolution (which can be quite small). We noticed this problem on our tube site, and since confirmed it happens with every other tube site that we've tested.

We also tested on 2 different Galaxy S3's, one with the latest updates and one without any updates in the last few weeks. The one with the latest updates plays the video at the original resolution (very small on these phones) and the one with the latest updates plays the videos automatically expanded to use the full screen.

I'm wondering if there is a way to force Android (from a website) to always play the videos expanded, and if not, if this is a bug of one of the latest updates?

Thanks!